Integral involving erf
I would greatly appreciate if I could get some help in the following integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)}{a^{2} +x^{2}}{\rm d}x
$$
A similar post was this one. The above is with $\operatorname{erf}$ instead of ${\rm e}^{-x^{2}}$.
Any further ideas are also appreciated.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Oh nothing is unclear there. The integral I want is the one with erf(x). I just linked that page as it might be related and/or helpful.

Assuming that $a$ is large
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)}{a^{2} +x^{2}}{\rm d}x=\frac \pi{2a}-\frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \, \frac{n!}{(2n+1)\,a^{2n}}$$ which is the expansion of
$$\frac{1}{2a^2\sqrt{\pi}} G_{2,3}^{2,2}\left(a^2\Bigg\vert \begin{array}{c}  \frac{1}{2},1 \\  \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0 \\ \end{array} \right)$$ given by Mathematica.
If $a$ is small
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)}{a^{2} +x^{2}}{\rm d}x=\frac 1{\sqrt \pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Big( \alpha_n-\frac {2\log(a)+\gamma}{(2n+1)\,\Gamma(n+1)}\Big)\, a^{2n}$$ where the $\alpha_n$ form the (unknown ?) sequence
$$\left\{2,\frac{5}{9},\frac{19}{100},\frac{89}{1764
   },\frac{83}{7776},\frac{1627}{871200},\frac{677
   }{2433600},\frac{229}{6350400},\cdots\right\}$$

But how is $\Gamma \left( n \right)$ defined at $n = 0$?

@SImon. Thanks for pointing ! I had a shift of $1$ somewhere.

For all $a > 0$,
$
\begin{align}
\DeclareMathOperator {\erf}{erf}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\erf \left( x \right)}{{x}^{2} + {a}^{2}} \text {d} x
& = \frac {1}{a} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\erf \left( a x \right)}{{x}^{2} + 1} \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {1}{a \sqrt {\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {2}{{x}^{2} + 1} \int_{0}^{a x} {e}^{- {u}^{2}} \text {d} u \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {1}{a \sqrt {\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {2}{{x}^{2} + 1} \int_{0}^{a} \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} t} \bigg[ \int_{0}^{t x} {e}^{- {u}^{2}} \text {d} u \bigg] \text {d} t \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {1}{a \sqrt {\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {2 x}{{x}^{2} + 1} \int_{0}^{a} {e}^{- {t}^{2} {x}^{2}} \text {d} t \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {1}{a \sqrt {\pi}} \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {2 x}{{x}^{2} + 1} {e}^{- {t}^{2} {x}^{2}} \text {d} x \text {d} t \\
& = \frac {1}{a \sqrt {\pi}} \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{x + 1} {e}^{- {t}^{2} x} \text {d} x \text {d} t \\
& = \frac {1}{a \sqrt {\pi}} \int_{0}^{a} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{x} {e}^{- {t}^{2} \left( x - 1 \right)} \text {d} x \text {d} t \\
& = \frac {1}{a \sqrt {\pi}} \int_{0}^{a} {e}^{{t}^{2}} \, \text {E}_{1} \left( {t}^{2} \right) \text {d} t.
\end{align}
$
I cannot proceed any further, unfortunately.

My version of Mathematica appears to simplify the final equation to
$$
\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{\pi}} G_{2,3}^{2,2}\left(a^2\Bigg\vert
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{2},1 \
\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$
in terms of the Meijer G-Function.

@RobertLee $$\frac{1}{2a^2\sqrt{\pi}} G_{2,3}^{2,2}\left(a^2\Bigg\vert \begin{array}{c}  \frac{1}{2},1 \  \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0 \ \end{array} \right)$$ In fact, the problem is quite simple.
